# Is there a way to bundle a JS library inside a UMD library bundle?

Tags: angular, date-fns, ng-packagr, umd, ngx-build-plus

I am building an Angular library and the client of the library needs to use it as a UMD module. I have the need to use some libraries such as [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns). When building the library it throws the following warnnings:

```sh
Bundling to UMD
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'date-fns/locale' in output.globals – guessing 'locale'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'date-fns' in output.globals – guessing 'dateFns'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'date-fns-tz' in output.globals – guessing 'dateFnsTz'
```

I am using the [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) to bundle the library and the libraries that have a UMD module can have the external name fixed in the ng-package.json file liek the following:

```json
{
...
  "lib": {
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "ngx-mask": "ngx-mask",
      ...
    },
...
```

The [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) creates a UMD module file that inside expects to find a `dateFns` in the global scope (`global.dateFns`). The problem is that the `date-fns` library does not provide a UMD module for the current version that the client can use. Is there a way to provide the necessary `date-fns` code inside the UMD bundle (the best option would be to make use of the tree-shacking capabilities but if not, include all `date-fns` code is also an option)? Or any workaround the client can do when using my library UMD?